# Cannot Assign multimap iterator private multimap member begin in const member function

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, constants, multimap

I am trying to iterate through a multimap, which is a private member of my class, in a public member function so I can traverse the multimap and print the elements. I know that if I make the print function below non-const it works, but I cannot fully understand why it doesn't work with the const. I'm assuming that assigning the iterator (my_map.begin()) allows the multimap to be modified but the const modifier won't allow this and thus, the code will not compile.Can anyone give me a clear and more in depth explanation as to why this does not work with the const function? I'm fairly new to using the STL containers and am just trying to gain a higher understanding of their functionality. Thanks for all and any help. (C++ code below)
(P.S. Just to be as clear as possible, I am not asking how to iterate through a multimap. Thanks again.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <map>

// Synonymous types for my  multimap and multimap iterator
typedef std::multimap<int, std::string> mm;
typedef mm::iterator mit;

class Foo
{
private:
  mm my_map;
  static int count;

public:
  Foo() {}
  void add(const std::string&);
  void print() const;
};

int Foo::count = 0;

void Foo::add(const std::string& s)
{
  my_map.insert(std::make_pair(count++, s));
}

**// This is the implementation of the that breaks my code**
void Foo::print() const
{
  mit it = my_map.begin(); // **I do not fully understand why this does not work.**
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get an iterator in a const function then you can't use **iterator**, but have to use **const_iterator** instead. So you would have to change the *mit* type:

`typedef mm::const_iterator mit;`

Here it's compiling and running:
https://godbolt.org/z/jM4rK6556

Or another approach would be not to force a type and let it infer whatever it wants, by changing line inside print:

`auto it = my_map.begin();`

Here is running version of that:
https://godbolt.org/z/rTv6xqPqq

For the future it would be better if you would include the error you are getting inside the question so others know and it's easier to google. Even reading the error is giving the hint of what is happening:

```
<source>: In member function 'const void Foo::print() const':
<source>:31:24: error: conversion from 'std::multimap<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator' {aka 'std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >::const_iterator'} to non-scalar type 'mit' {aka 'std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >::iterator'} requested
   31 |   mit it = my_map.begin();
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

So it's saying it can't convert from type A to type B when you compare the types, the difference is obvious, here is the type A:

`std::multimap<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator`

So your **mit** type is not matching what **my_map.begin()** is returning.

Comment: The only reason I want to make this function const is for protective programming (i.e. to prevent any accidental changes to class members)

Comment: @yazgiDev now I get you, I changed my answer, I provided 2 solutions for you

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thanks so much Krug, appreciate the help and I'll be sure to include the compiler error in the future. Thanks again, really appreciate you taking the time.